# Combo is not taking proper width in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I have recently upgraded my Ext version from 4.0.7 to 4.1

I have Grid with combo attached at the top using "tbar" config. 
Now the problem that I am facing is even if there is data or no data , my combo is not taking proper width. I have given width then also it is not working properly.

I have attached image for reference please have a loot at it.

Here is my Grid Code

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
id: 'SourceGridPanelId',
forceFit: true,
autoScroll:true,
store: sourceGridStore,
sortableColumns:false,
enableColumnHide:false,
tbar: createSourceSiteCombo(sourceSiteStore)
```

Here is my Combo Code

```
var sourceCombo= Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
id: "sourceSiteID",
fieldLabel:'Select Site',
inputId: "sourceSiteID_input",
store: sourceSiteStore,
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'sourceSiteName',
valueField: 'sourceSiteId',
width:200
 });
```

[image]
Please suggest what is missing here.

```
var combo=Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', 
            {
                multiSelect : false,
                id:'SelectComponentId',
                name:'SelectComponentId',
                allowBlank: true,
                inputId:'SelectComponentId_input',
                hideTrigger: false,
                editable: false,
                selectOnFocus: false,
                typeAhead: false,
                disabled: false,
                readOnly: false,
                width: 312,
                store: [['-1','Select User'],['59','Yagna Tel Clear']],
                value:'-1',
                renderTo:'UserBO_SelectComponentId_Div',
                triggerAction: 'all'
            });
```

in the above code If i remove the width it works fine, but take default width, but I want to assign the width.
Please suggest what is missing here

Answer (score 2):

The width is including `labelWidth`.
So if your label of the field has width e.g. 200 and you wish the width of the field to be 200 too, you need to set the width to 400 (+margin)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  You need to take the field label out of the combobox config and instead set it up in this manner, with a text object in the toolbar of the fieldname:

```
dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: "toolbar",
                dock: "top",
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: "tbtext",
                        style: "font-weight:bold;",
                        text:  "Select Site:"
                    },
                    createSourceSiteCombo(sourceSiteStore)
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I believe that the fieldLabel dom object created from fieldLabel screws up the toolbar rendering for some reason.

(Docked items takes the place of tbar and is now the standard way to create toolbars).

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply, but still I am not able to get the proper combo, but if I remove the width then its works fine. Please suggest what is missing here

Comment: I have edited my fist post, please read it and reply the same

Comment: I see "renderTo:'UserBO_SelectComponentId_Div'" in your code, which means you did not try my solution correctly.

Comment: No actaully the problem was I have included wrong ext-all.css , 
I got the Answer. 
Thanks for your help